# How to specify lsp configuration messages in emacs?

Tags: lsp-mode, config, rust

I'm trying to configure rust analyzer to expand proc macros.  According to it's documentation I have to configure my editor (i.e. emacs) to send this JSON as a LSP message:

```json
{
  "cargo": {
    "loadOutDirsFromCheck": true,
  },
  "procMacro": {
    "enable": true,
  }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in Emacs's documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Does calling the `lsp-rust-analyzer-expand-macro` function not work? It’s documented here: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-rust-analyzer/#macro-expansion

Comment: @db48x No, this function refers to declarative macros not procedural ones.  If I try it nonetheless, I get this error message: "No macro found at point, or it could not be expanded."

Comment: I see. Well, let me see if I have gathered enough information to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are asking about the configuration options listed [in the rust-analyzer documentation](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#configuration).

I wasn’t able to find out much about the subject in the `lsp-mode` documentation, so instead I took a quick peek in the `lsp-rust` source code. I soon found that there is a function called `lsp-rust-analyzer--make-init-options` that returns the data structure that will be encoded as JSON and sent to the server. You can view the source inside Emacs (type `C-h f` and enter the function name; it opens a help buffer for the function which includes a link to its source code), but it is also viewable [on GitHub](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/8.0.0/clients/lsp-rust.el#L623-L670).

If you look through this giant thing, you’ll eventually see `:cargo` and `:procMacro` sections. Specifically, you’ll see this:

```lisp
:procMacro (:enable ,(lsp-json-bool lsp-rust-analyzer-proc-macro-enable))
```

which uses the variable `lsp-rust-analyzer-proc-macro-enable` to enable or disable support for procedural macros. Similarly:

```lisp
:cargo (…
        :loadOutDirsFromCheck ,(lsp-json-bool lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-run-build-scripts)
        …)
```

does the same thing with the `lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-run-build-scripts` variable.

Both of these variables refer to customizable settings. To edit them, you can just run `M-x customize-group`, and then type `lsp-rust-analyzer` at the prompt. This lists all of the settings for the `lsp-rust-analyzer` module, and gives you a nice interface for editing them.

It also turns out that these variables are both documented in the `lsp-mode` [documentation](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-rust-analyzer/#lsp-rust-analyzer-proc-macro-enable); I had simply failed to notice them.